# Type error when implementing binary search

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code:

```
open Array

let binSearch a x =
    let l = ref 0 in
    let r = ref (length a) in
    let m = ref 0 in
    while l < r do
        !m := (!l + !r) / 2; (*line 8*)
        if (a.(!m) = x) then
        begin
            !r := !m;
            !l := !r
        end
        else if (a.(!m) > x) then
            !p := !m
        else
            !l := !m + 1
    done;
    a.(!l) = x
;;
```

when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
File "binSearch.ml", line 8, characters 2-4:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
     'a ref
```

Why is the compiler expecting `'a ref`?

Comment: honestly, writing ocaml in imperative style is quit ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to put `!` on the left side of the `:=` operator. Operator `:=` has type `'a ref -> 'a -> unit`, in other words there should be a reference to `'a` at the left side and `'a` at the right side. So, instead of:

```
 !r := !m (* WRONG *)
```

you need

```
 r := !m
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a bit confused. I have to use imperative ocaml for studies and it's awful

Comment: Yeah, reference are not the cleanest part of the language. But if you have choice, I would suggest you to use records with explicit mutable fields whenever possible. The syntax would be much more clean.